# Run gradle task only on windows

Tags: gradle, operating-system, dependency-management, gradle-task

I have some task:

```
task foo {
    //Do something
}
foo.dependsOn(":bar:baz")
foo.dependsOn(":bar2:baz2")
```

This task should only run on windows. I know, I could do:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

task foo {
    if (!Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

But this would still trigger the execution of the dependency tasks (:bar:baz and :bar2:baz2).

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You could basically add `onlyIf { !Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) }` to the *foo* task, but that would still execute *baz* and *baz2*. Gradle is like that. You'd have to add the `onlyIf` to the dependency tasks, too.

Comment: Or you declare the dependency only when not on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I now just wrapped the entire `foo.dependsOn(...)` lines into a `if(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {...}`.